# Save every computation without making MatLab run slowly

Tags: matlab

I have main.m and other tens of m-files associated with that main m-file. In total they are more than 5000 lines.

Because of this big size of the program, it's really hard to debug.

If I eliminate every ";" then MatLab prints everything so that I can track back what this program is doing more easily.

However, MatLab runs slowly when it prints everything (because it takes time to print them all).

To be concrete, if I do

```
diary 'out.txt'
a=1
diary off
```

then out.txt has "a=1" in it, but if I do

```
diary 'out.txt'
a=1;
diary off
```

then out.txt doesn't have anything.

I just want to see/save every variable that MatLab computed until it hit an error to an output file like out.txt (so that I can easily track where the error has come from), while at the same time not slowing down the program execution. Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: Would using the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) be an option? Note also the availability of various types of [breakpoints](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/set-breakpoints.html).

Comment: `dbstop if error` may be helpful here if you're encountering an error. Then you can inspect the relevant variables

Comment: @mikkola Thank you. But breakpoints alone weren't enough. This program has more than 5000 lines. To track the source of error, I had to actually have a complete output file.

Comment: @Suever Thank you but if I do "dbstop if error" then I can see the variables that were saved right before getting the error. But to track the root source of the error, I need to track way way before that.

Comment: @user42459 You can use `dbup` and `dbdown` to go up and down the call stack to where your error occured.